# Suppress sftp's info and errors but show progress

Tags: bash, sftp, file-descriptors

I have this

```bsh
sftp -q my_host:my_dir 1>/dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
  some_command
  some_command
  some_command
  some_command
  put foo bar
  some_command
  exit
EOF
```

This suppresses:

- banner and motd due to `-q`
- info and errors due to `1>/dev/null 2>&1` (e.g. cannot delete file, directory exists)

But it also suppresses `put`'s progress meter.

Can I show progress, but not info and errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append your SFTP command with this:

```
$SFTP_COMMAND | pv | grep -v "Connected\|Fetching"
```